# In a rental agreement payRent function is not working or not updating on MIST!

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mist, contract-design, remix

I want to implement a Car rental agreement.

In Customer contract there in stract with 4 field. And a registerToProvider function. In Provider contract there are two function to set rent and registration fee. All these are working fine. If a customer register to provider service, and provider set some rent and registration fee it works and in MIST it shows.

But when customer call the payRent or payRegistration fee these are not working and no update on MIST. can u please check my code and say what is the problem.

```
contract CarRentalServiceCustomer is GeneralAccount{
    string public customerName;
    string public postalAddress;
    string public phoneNumber;
    string public emailAddress;

    mapping(address=>CarRentService) public rentCar;

    struct CarRentService{ 
        bool active;
        uint lastUpdate;
        uint registrationFee;   
        uint rent;              
    }

    function CarRentalServiceCustomer(string _name,string _postalAddress,string _phoneNumber,string _emailAddress){
        customerName  = _name;
        postalAddress = _postalAddress;
        phoneNumber   = _phoneNumber;
        emailAddress  = _emailAddress;
    }

    function registerToCarRentalServiceProvider(address _providerAddress) onlyOwner {

        rentCar[_providerAddress] = CarRentService({
                                    active: true, 
                                    lastUpdate: now,
                                    registrationFee: 0,
                                    rent: 0
                                    });
    }

    function setRegistrationFee(uint _registrationFee) {
        if(rentCar[msg.sender].active){
            rentCar[msg.sender].lastUpdate      = now;
            rentCar[msg.sender].registrationFee = _registrationFee;
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }

    function setCarRent(uint _rent) {
        if(rentCar[msg.sender].active){
            rentCar[msg.sender].lastUpdate = now;
            rentCar[msg.sender].rent       = _rent;
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }

    function payRegistrationFeeToCarRentalServiceProvider(address _providerAddress) returns (bool){

        bool regFeeStatus = true;
        if(_providerAddress.send(rentCar[_providerAddress].registrationFee))
        {
            rentCar[_providerAddress].registrationFee = 0;
            return regFeeStatus;
        }
        else{
            return !regFeeStatus;
        }
    }

    function payRentToCarRentalServiceProvider(address _providerAddress) returns (bool){

        bool payStatus = true;
        if(_providerAddress.send(rentCar[_providerAddress].rent))
        {
            rentCar[_providerAddress].rent = 0;
            return payStatus;
        }
        else{
            return !payStatus;
        }
    }

    function unsubscribeFromCarRentalService(address _providerAddress){
        if(rentCar[_providerAddress].active = false && rentCar[_providerAddress].rent == 0 
        && rentCar[_providerAddress].registrationFee == 0 ){
            rentCar[_providerAddress].active = false;
        } else {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

when i call these function the transaction works properly but status is not changing. Kindly see the below image. I want after sending the rent both rent and registration fee will be 0.

[image]

Comment: Possible to put the rest of the contract up? This has undefined structs and other issues so it can't compile. We don't see .rent set anywhere and this is a problem ( send(0) ) but it's not necessarily *the* problem. Need to see what the rest is doing.

Comment: I have upload the full code....can please have a look...

Comment: Thanks. I got it to compile by removing "is General Account" and the onlyOwner modifers. Good enough for troubleshooting. Found some problems.

Comment: Is the problem with Inherent contract or modifier. Modifier is imp for security. Sorry i am totally a newbie. Please feel free to suggest me to develop this contract.

Comment: I have a plan to add some functionalities like #customer can choose car # for example provider has 5 car then customer can not rent the car and a message will shoe all cars booked. #provider has a database how many customer is registered in the service.... But how can i map that i have no idea....

Comment: Helpful. Thanks. So the contract is for one retail rental car desk (let's stick to one shop) like I have dealt with, and they have a fleet of cars that can only be rented to one person at a time, the rate is set by the office and the customer is a party to the contract. So, it's three things. 1) The inventory and availability. 2) The rental rate (varies by agreement) so set by the service desk, and then 3) the customer pays the bill when the car is returned. Some fairly tricky interactions around price and process. About right? Tough first project! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confused about what's supposed to be going on. Missing "GeneralAccount", so assuming that's where the payable functions are.

After some fiddling, I found the sequence but I'm very confused about who's who and why we're doing certain things.

I made minor changes to support the test:

1. Removed is `GeneralAccount` (missing)
2. Removed `onlyOwner` (missing)
3. Added a do-nothing function `payTestFunds() payable`.

**Test:**

I looked at the various things that have to happen first for this function to work, and came up with a sequence:

1. Sent contract some Eth with the `payable` function I added. Quite important, because if the contract doesn't have money, the `send()` will fail.
2. Sent my address to `registerToCarRentalServiceProvider`

[image]

3. Sent "1" to `setCarRent`
   [image]
4. Checked `rentCar[myAddress]`. 1. Correct. 
   [image]
5. Sent my address to `payRentToCarRentalServiceProvider`
   [image]
6. Checked rentCar[myAddress]. 0. Correct. 
   [image]

I'm having trouble following the business logic of it **but it is setting the values as expected**.

The functions that `send()` are structurally *unsafe* but it's off topic so setting it aside.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess this is the problem. I have the contract GeneralAccount and its modifier onlyowner also. My Customer contract inherit that contract. I guess my problem is i didnt give any ether to my contract account. i thought the ether of send function will deduct from my external account. I was wrong. Now when i deploy my customer contract with some ethar i am getting the following error in my MIST wallet. "It seem this transaction will fail, if "you submit it , it may consume all the gas you send."....and i have added the following payable function    function payTestFunds() payable{
 } Tnx a lot

Comment: simple add a function payTestFunds() payable{ } was not enough then i made my constructor also payable. Now in my contract account i have 5 ether now i pay the bill but still same show the old value...not becoming 0 after paying the rent...

Comment: edited my answer with pictures. I think this contract might be too busy to find firm footing.

Comment: strange thing...i have also tried similar....but not working...

Comment: One thing that jumped out during testing was the inconsistent use of addresses passed in and msg.sender. I had to be careful that the addresses I passed to functions would match msg.sender in setCarRent() because the code works that way.

Comment: sorry man i disturbed u a lot...i can not able to solve this tiny problem how can i build a big project...i am fad up....for last try here is my complete code https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.9+commit.364da425.js